# Javascript return in function in object won't show alert box

Tags: javascript, function, object, return, alert

So basically i have this code which has a return in a function which should then display the returned variable "Price" but the alert box does not show. 
If i delete all code except alert it will. I can't find any misspelled words or pieces of code. Could you help me ?

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var auto = {
            merk: 'BMW',
            model: 1,
            aantal deuren: 5,
            bouwjaar: 1990,
            prijs : 20000,

            price: function(){
            return this.prijs;
            }
        };
        var x = auto.price();
        alert(x);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not useful to mix languages Nederlands en Engels ;)

Answer (score 6):

You have invalid property name in the object:

```
aantal deuren: 5,
```

If the property name is not valid identifier you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
var auto = {
    merk: 'BMW',
    model: 1,
    "aantal deuren": 5,
    bouwjaar: 1990,
    prijs: 20000,

    price: function () {
        return this.prijs;
    }
};
var x = auto.price();
alert("prijs");
```

Comment: Stylistically, `aantalDeuren: 5` would be more in keeping with normal JavaScript property naming standards.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to name this property as `aantalDeuren: 5`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `''` for `'aantal deuren': 5,` or remove space from `aantaldeuren: 5,` object property